# AWS S3, how can I make the asset paths equal the domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, path, filepath

So, I just set my site up at http://www.deesign.today.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ (Name servers are propagating) -- you will see that the paths to my assets are wrong. I'm using:
`www.mydomain.com/css/main.css`, but that obviously is not working because the asset files are stored elsewhere.

I could just change the paths, but the paths are fugly! :) :
`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.deesign.today/css/main.css`

I want to simply point to my asset files, like this:
`http://www.deesign.today/css/main.css`

I cannot figure out how to do this :( I've been trying to find an answer for hours. I could setup a subdomain `assets` and add a `cname` record, but I don't want to do that.

Has anyone done this yet?

Comment: Is it your subdomain?

Comment: @KushalVora yes it is :)

Comment: So when you transfer it to main domain, it will automatically set up. Don't worry about subdomain. Otherwise you need to write fixed path if you use subdomain.

Comment: If you agree with this answer, please mark my answer.

Comment: @KushalVora thanks! So, I'll just be patient and wait until the name server change propagates.

Comment: @KushalVora I'll mark it correct after the ns updates and it works :)

Comment: At least just give me point thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you transfer it to main domain, it will automatically set up. Don't worry about subdomain. Otherwise you need to write fixed path if you use subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, NS finally updated and everything works. I can't believe I wasted so much time trying to find a solution.